# Create a photo finish from a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

In sports with close finishes a [photo finish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_finish) is used: this takes repeatedly a vertical line of pixels of the finish line and assembles them next to each other into a photo. Now the horizontal position in the photo corresponds to the time. This is done with special equipment but could it be also recreated from a video using ffmpeg? Say, you take the vertical pixel line from the middle of the frame and assemble them into a photo.